# Unable to signUp a new user in quickblox

Tags: java, android, chat, quickblox

I have been trying to add a new user to quickblox referring to the code provided in the sample-chat provided for android.

I am using the following code.

Authenticate using APP_ID,AUTH_ID and SECRET_ID.

```
QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
```

Create an application session

```
QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
@Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
                getAllUser();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                // print errors that came from server
                DialogUtils.showLong(context, errors.get(0));
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

//Sign up a new user

// Register new user

final QBUser user = new QBUser("userlogin", "userpassword");

QBUsers.signUp(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
        // success
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
       // error
    }
});
```

User signup is not working.I am able to login using an already registered user via quickblox administration panel.

I want to create a new user as soon as I login and create chat service with the same login.I am new to quickblox and java any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry for the update.signUp API call isnt working.I have updated the problem above

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to call **QBUsers.signUp** inside CreateSession **onSuccess**  block

Because these QuickBlox queries are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "**QbAuth.createSession**", use "**QBUsers.Signup**" for registering a new user.
This is because the former method is used for creating session, which is only possible if you have a user logged into the quickblox. 
So, use the latter method and register a user into the quickblox first.
If you are still facing the issue, then just check your "Auth Keys", "Auth Secret" in your application, if they are correct.